# How to copy-by-value (not by reference) a CPLEX IloArray, the easy way

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor, cplex

I work with CPLEX and C++ via Concert Technology and a recurrent issue I am encountering is that internally the `IloArray` structures seem to be overloaded `vector` structures with copy-by-reference operators. Which I must acknowledge is a quite neat and memory efficient way of handling the array structures.

Yet... This implies that making `IloIntArray Array_copy = Array`, for a previously declared and initialized `IloIntArray Array`, will make a reference copy of `Array` into `Array_copy`. Hence, any change in `Array` is automatically transferred to `Array_copy`. The same applies to multi-dimensional `IloArray` structures via the `add()` routine.

Let us say, for instance, that I need to populate a 2D `IloArray<IloIntArray> Array2D(env)`, inside a for-loop indexed in `i = 1` to `iSize`, storing in each position of `Array2D[i]`, from `i = 1` to `iSize`, the values of `Array` which will be different at each iteration of the loop. Making either:

1. `Array2D[i].add(Array)` or,
2. `Array2D[i] = Array`, assuming `Array2D` i-dimension was initially set to be of size `iSize`.

Fails to make the intended copy-by-value, since each time, a copy-by-reference is made to the elements of the i-dimension and you end up with all identical elements, equal to the last value of `Array`.

Now, besides, making my own ***copy-by-value operator*** constructor (*Option I*) or a ***copy routine*** (*Option II*) receiving, both, the origin and destination arrays as well as the position of the destination array (*e.g. multi-dimensional array*) where the origin array is to be copied.

Is there another way to make the copy-by-value? In any case, can you help me decide which one of these options is more neat and/or memory efficient? Intuitively I deem *Option I* to be the more efficient, but I don't know how to do it...

Thanks in advance for your help
Y

Comment: AFAIK, here are the methods to copy an array:  1) `for` loop. 2) `memcpy` 3) DMA 4) Unrolled (one assignment per slot).  If you go with assembly language, some processors have instructions for copying large blocks of memory.

Comment: BTW, one use of pointers and references is to avoid the execution cost of copying an array (such as passing to functions).  The idea is that passing a pointer or reference takes less room and less execution time than a large array.

Comment: Which is why I mentioned that the utilization of pointers and references do leads to a more neat and memory efficient way. Though, it is preventing me from doing what I intend to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I am solving my own issue by implementing a **copy()** function.

I have *typedefed* my multi-dimensional arrays as follows:

`typedef IloArray<IloIntArray> Ilo2IntArray;` and `typedef IloArray<IloNumArray> Ilo2NumArray` and so on for three or four dimensional integer or numeric arrays.

An example of my `Ilo3IntArray copy(Ilo3IntArray origin)` overload of the copy function I am using as a patch to make copy-by-value copies, is as follows:

```
Ilo3IntArray copy(Ilo3IntArray origin) {

IloInt iSize = origin.getSize();
Ilo3IntArray destination(env, iSize);
IloInt jSize = origin[0].getSize();
IloInt zSize = origin[0][0].getSize();

for (IloInt i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
    destination[i] = Ilo2IntArray(env, jSize);

    for (IloInt j = 0; j < jSize; j++) {
        destination[i][j] = IloIntArray(env, zSize);

        for (IloInt z = 0; z < zSize; z++) {
            destination[i][j][z] = origin[i][j][z];
        }
    }
}

return destination;

// Freeing Local Memory
destination.end();
}
```

Your comments and/or better answers are welcome!!!